# What Ubuntu alternatives will still be supported after 12.04

Tags: 12.04, release

I have read today that Kubuntu might not be supported after the 12.04 release. Is this true? and if yes, what other ubuntu alternatives have the same fate and why?

Comment: You probably misread it. Kubuntu is just not financially supported by Canonical. Just like the other flavours, it will continue to be supported by the community while Canonical still provides the infrastructure and the resources.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the IRC chat for Kubuntu yesterday, the Kubuntu Devs were a little disappointed they lost *paid financial support* from Canonical, but they will continue to develop and support Kubuntu regardless of the financial support.  Lubuntu, Xubuntu, etc. all are similar in that Canonical does not give them direct funding.

---

To give an actual answer to what is actually "supported" 12.04 and later, in terms of "Official Derivatives" (derivatives which are official, to some extent, regardless of Canonical paid financial support), the following are, at the very least, the current derivatives which are still actively considered "official":

- Ubuntu
- Kubuntu
- Xubuntu
- Lubuntu

Comment: Ok thanks Thomas, I for one was one of the KDE users until Unity came alone but KDE is very good. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Sure, its not a problem :)

Answer (score 4):

The article I read said that Kubuntu will not have a paid Canonical employee on the project.  The result is Kubuntu will be on a similar playfield as Xubuntu/Lubuntu, which are still supported.

Comment: Phoronix is very misleading. It confused me a lot with the whole "will stop sponsor" and the words "dropping support".

Comment: I've noticed that the online computer media tend to blow things way out of proportion: they exagerate to the point of misleading.  It's difficult not to come away with the impression that they deliberately lie just to get hits.